# Unable to filter output of table when querying Office 365 licensing status

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to filter for the output from this command (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ).Licenses.ServiceStatus

Which looks like this:

```
ServicePlan               ProvisioningStatus
-----------               ------------------
MCOMEETADV                Success
ADALLOM_S_DISCOVERY       Disabled
EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION     PendingProvisioning
AAD_PREMIUM               Success
MFA_PREMIUM               Success
ONEDRIVE_BASIC            Success
VISIOONLINE               Success
EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION     PendingProvisioning
VISIO_CLIENT_SUBSCRIPTION Success
MCOPSTN1                  Success
EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION     PendingProvisioning
DYN365_CDS_VIRAL          Success
FLOW_P2_VIRAL             Success
EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION     PendingProvisioning
INTUNE_A                  PendingInput
EXCHANGE_S_FOUNDATION     PendingProvisioning
BI_AZURE_P2               Success
MCOEV                     Success
MICROSOFT_SEARCH          PendingProvisioning
WHITEBOARD_PLAN2          PendingProvisioning
MIP_S_CLP1                PendingProvisioning
MYANALYTICS_P2            Success
BPOS_S_TODO_2             Success
FORMS_PLAN_E3             Success
STREAM_O365_E3            Success
Deskless                  Success
FLOW_O365_P2              Success
POWERAPPS_O365_P2         Success
TEAMS1                    Success
PROJECTWORKMANAGEMENT     Success
SWAY                      Success
INTUNE_O365               PendingActivation
YAMMER_ENTERPRISE         Success
RMS_S_ENTERPRISE          Success
OFFICESUBSCRIPTION        Success
MCOSTANDARD               Success
SHAREPOINTWAC             Success
SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE      Success
EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE     Success
```

I'm filtering for Exchange_S_Enterprise and MCOEV.

I've tried (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ).Licenses.ServiceStatus | Select-Object Exchange

I've tried Where-Object

Which returns nothing

(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName ).Licenses.ServiceStatus

I'd like to do an if statement, to continue my script if EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE's provisioning status -eq "Success"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you digged into Service Status for one of your user, you would have seen that ServiceStatus is an object which contains several sublevels.

You need to get to the ServiceName to do your `Where` statement..

Here's a working example of this that will perform different actions on both **MCOEV** and **Exchange_S_Enterprise** if their provisionning status is `SUCCESS`.

```
$User = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'MyUser@MyDomain.com'

$PlanstoCheck = @('MCOEV', ' EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE')
$Plans = $User.Licenses.ServiceStatus.where( { $_.ServicePlan.ServiceName -in $PlanstoCheck })

Foreach ($Plan in $Plans) {
    if ($Plan.ProvisioningStatus -eq 'SUCCESS') {
        switch ($Plan.ServicePlan.ServiceName) {
            'MCOEV' { Write-Host 'Do thing #1' }
            'EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE' { 'Do THing #2' }
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging, you can use **F8** to execute only one line at a time.
In your case, loading a MSOL user at $User.Licenses.ServiceStatus, you can see there's a few level deeper. If you do a `GetType()` at that level, you'll also notice your current level is not a string, but yet another object, hence why comparing an object to a string did not produce the expected result.